# Вывод RSS на Wordpress - как получить автора? dc:creator

Tags: wordpress, xml, rss

Есть примерный код, для вывода RSS внешних сайтов на Wordpress:

```
<?php
// делаем функцию fetch_feed() доступной, обычно эта строка не нужна
include_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php';

// Получаем фид и создаем из него SimplePie объект.
$rss = fetch_feed( 'http://blog.ru/feed' );

// Проверяем, что объект успешно создан
if ( ! is_wp_error( $rss ) ) {
    // Указываем что максимум мы хотим выводить 5 записей фида
    $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity( 5 );

    // Создаем массив всех записей фида, начиная с первой записи (0 - начало)
    $rss_items = $rss->get_items( 0, $maxitems );
}
?>

<ul>
    <?php
    if ( $maxitems == 0 ) {
        echo '<li>Нет записей.</li>';
    } else { // Пробегаемся по массиву и выводим ссылку на каждую запись
        foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) { ?>
            <li>
                <a href='<?php echo esc_url( $item->get_permalink() ); ?>unread'
                   title='<?php echo 'Posted ' . $item->get_date( 'j F Y | g:i a' ); ?>'
                >
                    <?php echo esc_html( $item->get_title() ); ?>
                </a>
                                    <?php echo ( $item->get_content() ); ?>
                                
            </li>
        <?php }
    } ?>
```

Но, как получить с его помощью автора, то есть элемент <dc:creator>?
Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Нужно распарсить xml. Это вопрос по php.

Answer (score 1):

для того чтобы получить все данные об аторе исполльзуйте это метод

```
 $item->get_author()
```

он вернет вам обьект `SimplePie_Author` с которым вы можете работать.

если вам нужно получить только имя автора используйте следующий код

```
$item->get_author()->get_name()
```

он вернет вам строку с именем

Comment: ТС спрашивает об в авторах с чужого сайта. С контента, полученном по RSS.

Comment: И что не так с методом get_author() для этой задачи?

Comment: <?php echo ( $item->get_author()->get_name() ); ?> - не работает.

Если просто выводить автора, то выводит какие-то цифры-букв. Author это обычно email (который закрыт от всех):
`<author>invalid@example.com (Len)</author>
<dc:creator>Len</dc:creator>`

Наверное, здесь есть решение (последнее сообщение), но я не знаю, как применить его на wordpress:

http://xpoint.ru/forums/thread/43531.xhtml

Comment: скорее всего проблема с вашей лентой, для того что бы убедится  в корректной  работе метода $item->get_author()->get_name(), вы можете изменить ссылку ленты например на блог wordpress https://wordpress.com/blog/feed/

Comment: Понял в чём дело. В старых форматах rss вот так:
`<dc:creator>Andy RR</dc:creator>`, а в новых `<dc:creator><![CDATA[ Andy RR ]]></dc:creator>`. Wordpress умеет обрабатывать новый.

Comment: если проблема еще актуальна дайте ссылку на вашу ленту